# Placing Private Function in Subdirectories in Codeigniter/PHP not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am utterly and completely confused. I've looked through all the documentation and I can't find a solution. Setup: CI 2.1.3, QNAP server.

Problem: I cannot use a private function on a controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Signup extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    _loadcontent();
}

private function _loadcontent()
{
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
}

/* End of file signup.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/account/signup.php */
```

it won't work and gives an HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error). HOWEVER, placing the file in the main controller directory works. Does anybody have any clue? is this a bug? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "placing the file in the main controller directory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function using `$this`.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->_loadcontent();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. there was no thing on this in the user manual. I've been pulling me hair out for two days thinking it was a syntax error.